# How to remove many to many relation for queryset?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have a many to many relationship in my models  like this.

```
class Shift(models.Model):
    employees = models.ManyToManyField('account.Employee', 
                                       related_name='allocated_in',
                                       blank=True)
```

Say I have a particular instance of employee `employee`. I can remove him from single shift instance `shift` like this.

```
shift.employees.remove(employee)
```

How can I remove `employee` from every instance of a queryset of `Shift`?

```
shift_qs = Shift.objects.filter(date__gt=timezone.now().date)
```

I want to remove `employee` from every instance in `shift_qs` in **a single query**. Preferably without **looping over queryset**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the intermediate model:

```
IModel = shift_qs.employees.through
IModel.objects.filter(shift__in=shift_qs, employee=employee).delete()
```